# Laravel 4 HybridAuth Yahoo authentication

Tags: php, laravel, yahoo, hybridauth

I'm using HybridAuth 2.1.1-dev for authenticating with Laravel 4.

It works with Google and Facebook but I always get this error with Yahoo:

```
Undefined index: oauth_token
```

I registered a project on Yahoo Developer, with options:

- For getting private user data access
- APIs for private user data access: Social Directory > Read Public
- Already verified my domain
- Already changed in config file:

  ```
  "Yahoo" => array("enabled" => true, "keys" => array("key" => "", "secret" => ""))
  ```

Comment: don't edit your question to show the answer. Instead add an answer.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new with StackOverflow. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: ok, but you haven't fixed it. Add an answer and put the solution in it, then edit the question to remove the solution you put in there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally it worked perfectly, for your information:

In HybridAuth config file, Yahoo configuration should be:

```
"Yahoo" => array (
    "enabled" => true,
    "keys"    => array ("key"    => "Your application key (Not application ID)",
                        "secret" => "Your application secret")
)
```